# Como enviar dados de um loop php para um input usando JS

Tags: php, javascript

Como enviar um dado de um loop em php onde cada input vai poder ser enviado para outro input que esta fora do loop php, estou tentando em javascript. Recebo od dados diretamente do banco de dados. Lembrando que o input nome fica fora e é o que recebe o valor.

```js
function passar(){ 
var valorA = document.getElementById("valorA"); 
var nome = document.getElementById("nome"); 
nome.value = valorA.value; 
};
```

```html
<?php
         $sql_lista = mysql_query("SELECT*FROM login LIMIT 0, 2"); 
    //aqui fazemos a contagem para exibição se caso ouver dados(quantidade)
   $sql_contar = mysql_num_rows($sql_lista);
      ?>

  <?php
     while($resultado = mysql_fetch_array($sql_lista)){ ?>    

<?php echo $resultado['usuario'];?>
 
    <form>

<INPUT TYPE="text" SIZE="3" name="valorA" id="valorA" value="<?php echo $resultado['lo_id'];?>"></input>
 
<button type="button" onclick="passar();"> passar valores </button> 

   
 </form>
        
  <?php
  //fechamos o while
   } 
  ?>
 Nome:<input type="text" id="nome" size="10"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O atributo ID de um elemento deve ser único. Logo você deve alterar o id dos elementos de dentro do while, de modo que cada um receba um id único.

Pode-se resolver assim:

```
<input 
    TYPE="text" 
    SIZE="3" 
    name="valorA" 
    id="valorA_<?=$resultado['lo_id'] ?>" 
    value="<?php echo $resultado['lo_id'];?>" 
/>
```

Lembrando que `<input>` não existe tag de fechamento devendo ser fechada assim:

```
<input... />
```

No botão você passa o id como parâmetro

```
<button type="button" onclick="passar(<?=$resultado['lo_id']?>);"> passar valores </button>
```

E a sua função js ficará assim:

```
function passar(id){ 
    var valorA = document.getElementById("valorA"+id); 
    var nome = document.getElementById("nome"); 
    nome.value = valorA.value; 
};
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: caramba mano ce ajudou muito agora vou mudar esse codigo para o que eu quero obrigado mesmo, não estava sabendo como fazer sou pessimo em js.A sim precisei no codigo javascript retirar o valorA ficanco assim  var valorA = document.getElementById(id);

Comment: Opa... que bom que eu consegui te ajudar.

Comment: outra duvida @Thomas Lima e se eu não quiser pegar o id tipo pegar um nome, como faria isso?

Comment: Você pode usar atributos personalizados: data-titulo = "Meu titulo". Ai na sua função passar() você pegaria assim:
var elem = document.getElementById(id); 
var titulo = elem.getAttribute('data-titulo');